# Changing texture of rendered model at runtime in arcore

Tags: java, android, arcore

Cant find a way to change texture at runtime for my rendered model in arcore. Initial texture that I set, seems to be what I am stuck with.

```
  ModelRenderable.builder()
          .setSource(this, Uri.parse("test.sfb"))
          .build()
          .thenAccept(
                  modelRenderable -> {
                      faceRegionsRenderable = modelRenderable;
                      modelRenderable.setShadowCaster(false);
                      modelRenderable.setShadowReceiver(false);
                  });

  Texture.builder()
          .setSource(this, R.drawable.test)
          .build()
          .thenAccept(texture -> faceMeshTexture = texture);
```

How to change texture at runtime, after first selection of texture.